# react-native-calendar-strip future dates selection

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm developing reminder app and showing calendar on home page, for that using `react-native-calendar-strip` library, so now task is coming based on dates right? but when I'm selecting future dates after 2 months e.x. 28th Sept 2023 from now then calling API, api giving me skipped as a response and while running this api in postman it is giving `data: [ ]` and `status_code: 200`, so is there any issue with library or something else? I'm not sure can anyone please look into this ? I also searched for the issue in git of this library.